# MDL - Checkbox component

Tags: html, reactjs, checkbox, material-design-lite

Is it possible to have a link for the label of React-MDL checkbox component?  If yes, How can I achieve it?

The below snippet renders a checkbox field using the Checkbox component of react-mdl.

```
const renderCheckBoxField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) => (
  <Checkbox label={label}/>
);

<Field label='I agree to receive news and special offers' name="offers" component={renderCheckBoxField} type="checkbox"/>
<label htmlFor="offers"></label>
```

The below code does it, but as you can see it is definitely not the best way to have it. Is it possible to do something like above using the renderCheckBoxField for this as well?

```
<label className="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox is-upgraded">
  <input type="checkbox" className="mdl-checkbox__input" value="0" />
   <span className="mdl-checkbox__label">I agree to the &nbsp;<Link to='termsandconditions/' target='_blank'> Terms & Conditions </Link>
   </span>
   <span className="mdl-checkbox__focus-helper"></span>
   <span className="mdl-checkbox__box-outline"><span className="mdl-checkbox__tick-outline"></span></span>
</label>
```

The problem with this above code is that it doesn't allow me to check the box. Couldn't figure why that happens. I have all the related CSS included.
Thank you!

Comment: react-mdl seems to be deprecated!

Comment: Yes, It's moving to a new library web-components but still I wonder how to implement it. Do you have any idea doing it a better way with just Material Design Lite rather than using react-mdl ?